# $A \neq B \neq C$ implies are all different?

Tags: notation

Where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are sets. My doubt is if the notation includes the case $A \neq C$.

Comment: No, for example $\{1\}\ne\emptyset\ne\{1\}$ is a valid statement.

Comment: I would regard that notation as ambiguous.  If you want to say that the sets are all distinct, say that.  Similarly, if you mean to say that $A\neq B$ and $B\neq C$, say that.  Writing it this way is sure to cause confusion.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: Personally, I've always read $A\ne B\ne C$ as $A\ne B\land B\ne C$, just like I would not read $x\in A\in \mathcal P(X)$ as $A\cup x\subseteq X\land x\in A$.

Comment: No. But please avoid this notation when writing, since it can cause this type of confusion. Prefer $A \neq B$ and $B \neq C$ or make clear $A, B, C$ "all different from each other"

Comment: As stated in previous comments, it doesn't. I tried it on Python (which supports this notation), it doesn't...

Comment: @Nothingspecial What Python does is at best vaguely related to how mathematicians read notation. It is not a reliable way to check for the meaning of things. (Though in this case, it agrees.)

Comment: @EikeSchulte I agree that's true, it's not a reliable way because there might be exceptions. However, Python mostly agrees with usual notations. For example, it evaluates exponent operator from right to left....